# I am not able to query a pre-created database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am not able to query a **pre-created database**.
I created a `SQLite` database using `SQLiteDatabaseBrowser` and I populated it.
The following `query` works in the `SQLiteDatabaseBrowser`:

```
SELECT png FROM flags64 WHERE iso3='jpn' LIMIT 1
```

I moved the file in the folder `"../assets/databases"` in the android project into the Android Studio.
This is the code used to query the database from my android app:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
try {
    db = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mysticker.db").getPath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor result = null;
    try {
        result = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT png FROM flags64 WHERE iso3='%s' LIMIT 1", country.toLowerCase()), null);
        if (result.getCount()>0) {
            result.moveToFirst();
            byte[] png = result.getBlob(result.getColumnIndex("png"));

            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(png);
            playerCountryFlag.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("mySticker", e.getStackTrace().toString());
    } finally {
        if (result != null) {
            result.close();
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Debugging the code the query does not return any records.

Comment: 1st make sure country.toLowerCase() returns `jpn`. Then do not use String concatenation to build the query but use parameter binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openOrCreateDatabase()` does not open database files from assets but rather in your app's private data directory. You're essentially creating a new empty database.

Use [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to deploy a database file from assets to your app's private data dir.